# Duplicate main site into a MSM site, what native EE channel field values are duplicated?

Tags: ee2

I'm wondering if these native EE fieldtypes are supported with content duplication when creating a new MSM site. In my experience there are some 3rd party add-ons that don't support MSM site duplication.

- Grid
- Relationships
- Textarea (Rich Text)

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, Grid and Relationship native EE fields are not duplicated. Not sure why this is the case.